# C++: Console window has weird borders..?

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, winapi

I have created a program that - among other things - changes the console window size and removes the window borders from it (mostly by setting the window style to WS_POPUP).
Now on *my* computer, the application is executed with no problems whatsoever, but when I run the code in another computer (or in VirtualBox), I get some funky glitches.

Here's an image that shows these glitches I speak of:
[image: glitches with awesome depth of field]

These glitches appearead if the user moved/opened a window on top of the console window and then brought the console window to the top again.
So naturally, I thought that the easiest way to get rid of this problem would be to make the console window *always on top*, but that didn't help, because now the glitches just take their *'background'* from whatever was there before the new window was moved/opened on top *(or rather, below)* the console window.
It seems that the glitched areas are somehow cached/stored somewhere, and do not notice that the window has been resized.

```
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rClnt);
rClnt.top += 1;
rClnt.bottom -= 2;
rClnt.right -= 1;
SetWindowRgn(hWnd, CreateRectRgnIndirect(&rClnt), 1);
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
exStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
exStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle);
BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, ((rScr.right / 2) - rWnd.right / 2) - 1, (rScr.bottom / 2) - rWnd.bottom / 2, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOSIZE);// After this I just use ShowWindow().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the glitches.

All I did was I moved the `SetWindowRgn()` function just above the `ShowWindow()` (which would be at the very end of the code snippet).
This removed the glitched areas, and now my window displays correctly.

There was a bug where the window was not centered afterwards, but I fixed it by changing

```
if(!SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, ((rScr.right / 2) - rWnd.right / 2) - 1, (rScr.bottom / 2) - rWnd.bottom / 2, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOSIZE))
```

to

```
if(!SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, ((rScr.right / 2) - rClnt.right / 2) - 1, (rScr.bottom / 2) - rClnt.bottom / 2, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOSIZE))
```